# Probability of an event happening exactly once out of 3 times

Tags: probability

I have to solve this problem:

> Three urns each contain ten gems:
>
> - Urn 1 contains 6 rubies and 4 emeralds.
> - Urn 2r contains 8 rubies and 2 emeralds.
> - Urn 2e contains 4 rubies and 6 emeralds.
>
> The following procedure is used to select two
>   gems. First, one gem is drawn at random from urn 1. If this first gem
>   is a ruby, then a second gem is drawn at random from urn 2r; however,
>   if the first gem is an emerald, then the second gem is drawn at random
>   from urn 2e.
>
> Suppose that this procedure is independently replicated three times.
>   What is the probability that a ruby is obtained on the second draw
>   exactly once?

My solution was to calculate the probability of obtaining a ruby on the second draw, where I got $0.64$ which is also correct according to the solutions.

Then to solve the actual problem I wanted to use R, writing

```
pbinom(1,3,0.64) - pbinom(0,3,0.64)
```

, getting $0.248832$ as an answer.

Yet the correct solution would be $0.3549$.

Comment: Are the gems drawn with replacement?

Comment: Yes (charminimum)

Comment: I get the exact same answer as you in that case, $(0.64)^{1}*(0.36)^{2}*\left(\array{3\\1}\right)=0.248832$. Is the answer of $0.3549$ explained in any way?

Comment: No, we got the sheet with all the answers which our TA (teaching assistant) calculated. There was nothing wrong in the last 50 exercises, but maybe he made a mistake this time.

Comment: I also match your answer...haven't been able to think of any variant that yields $.3549$.

Comment: Hmm thank you. I guess the answer is simply wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get this right, we replicate procedure three times and want to know probability of obtaining precisely one ruby during the second draw.

We can avoid a ruby on the second draw with probability $$0.6\cdot 0.2 + 0.4\cdot 0.6 = 0.36$$
We can obtain a ruby on second draw with probability (following computation really unnecessary)$$0.6\cdot 0.8 + 0.4\cdot 0.4 = 0.64 $$
There are three ways this can happen so your solution must be correct.

Comment: Hmm thank you. I guess the answer of the solutions is simply wrong.